# Express.js sendFile returning ECONNABORTED

Tags: node.js, express

On a simple node server running Express.js (3.8.6). I am attempting to use `sendFile` to send a simple HTML file to the client.

- The path is shown to be good from the file read.
- The cache is disabled on the browser.
- The code shown is the server.js file and is run from node directly

What am I missing?

**Code**

```js
//server.js

var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var path = require('path');

//Server views folder as a static in case that's required for sendFile(??)    
app.use('/views', express.static('views'));
var myPath = path.resolve("./views/lobbyView.html");

// File Testing
//--------------------------
//This works fine and dumps the file to my console window
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile(myPath, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  console.log (err ? err : data);
});

// Send File Testing
//--------------------------
//This writes nothing to the client and throws the ECONNABORTED error
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(myPath, null, function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });
  res.end();
});
```

**Project Setup**

[image: Project Setup]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're prematurely calling `res.end()`. Remember, that Node.js is asynchronous, thus what you're actually doing is cancelling your `sendFile` before it completes. Change it to :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(myPath, null, function(err){
    console.log(err);
    res.end();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thx, that was happening to me, i guess its because i have to improve my callback (async) thought.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem with download(file), now it works perfecto

```
 server.get('/download', (req, res) => {

    res.download('./text.txt', 'text.txt', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(404)
            res.end();
            console.log('download failed');
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log('downloaded seccefully');
            res.end();

        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).