# Node.js "Error: write ECONNABORTED" when working with streams

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to write a code, which will write a file (if it is not bigger than 1Mb and doesn't exist) on the server. When the file is too big, it throws for some reasons `Error: write ECONNABORTED` (from automatic tests). I have read from StackOverflow, the error shows, that you are [prematurely calling res.end()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36949631/13891817), but I can't find, where I call `res.end()` prematurely. Also tests for successfully loaded files fail.

```
fs.stat(filepath, (err, file) => {
  if (err) {
    if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
      const stream = new LimitSizeStream({limit: 1024*1024});
      const outStream = fs.createWriteStream(pathname);

      req.pipe(stream).pipe(outStream);

      stream.on('error', (e) => {
        stream.destroy();
        outStream.destroy();
        if (e instanceof LimitExceededError) {
          res.statusCode = 413;
          res.end('File is too big');
        } else {
          res.statusCode = 500;
          res.end('Internal error');
        }
      });

      outStream.on('error', (e)=> {
        stream.destroy();
        outStream.destroy();
        console.log('outStream error', e);
      });

      req.on('aborted', () => {
        stream.destroy();
        outStream.destroy();
      });

      outStream.on('end', () => {
        res.statusCode = 201;
        res.end('Successfully loaded');
      });
    }
  } else if (file.isFile()) {
    res.statusCode = 409;
    res.end('File already exists');
    return;
  };
});
```

Tests (not mine), which fail with ECONNABORTED:

```
it('when creating too big file - error 413', (done) => {
  const request = http.request(
    'http://localhost:3001/big.png',
    {method: 'POST'},
    (response) => {
      expect(
        response.statusCode,
        'status code of server is 413'
      ).to.equal(413);

  request.on('error', (err) => {
    // EPIPE/ECONNRESET error should occur because we try to pipe after res closed
    if (!['ECONNRESET', 'EPIPE'].includes(err.code)) done(err);
  });

  fse.createReadStream(path.join(fixturesFolder, 'big.png')).pipe(request);
});
```

Tests (not mine), which fail

```
it('successfully creates the file', (done) => {
  const request = http.request(
    'http://localhost:3001/small.png',
    {method: 'POST'},
    (response) => {
      expect(
        response.statusCode,
        'status code is 201'
      ).to.equal(201);

      expect(
        fse.existsSync(path.join(filesFolder, 'small.png')),
          'file small.png should be on a disk'
      ).to.be.true;

      done();
    });

    request.on('error', done);
    fse.createReadStream(path.join(fixturesFolder, 'small.png')).pipe(request);
});
```